# How do you override a user Maven settings file when building a grails project?

Tags: maven, grails, jenkins

I'm using Grails 2.4.1 to build a Grails plugin project via Jenkins & the Grails Release plugin (3.0.1) to publish that plugin to our Nexus repository.

The user that runs Jetbrains (jetbrains) on our build server already has a .m2/settings.xml file. That file defines some Mirrors that are causing havok when trying to publish plugins to our nexus repository. The mirror defined in the settings.xml file reroutes everything to the public 'group'.

What I would like to do is for specific jobs force maven to either ignore the settings.xml file all together or to specify my own.

I could put a file in the M2_HOME/conf directory but since the user directory already has a settings.xml file that contains mirrors it seems like anything I do in the M2_HOME/conf directory would be ignored.

I've seen the -s file-name-here solution, but I don't see any way to pass that through my grails publish-plugin command while building.

I'd also be open to solutions that redefine the mirror we have so that everything EXCEPT our internal repositories are rerouted.

The mirror block I have is:

```
<mirror>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    <name>Nexus Public Mirror</name>
    <url>http://maven.internal.website/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</mirror>
```

As per [the Maven Mirror guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html), I've tried:

```
<mirror>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
    <name>Nexus Public Mirror</name>
    <url>http://maven.internal.website/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</mirror>

<mirror>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <mirrorOf>external:*,!snapshots,!releases</mirrorOf>
    <name>Nexus Public Mirror</name>
    <url>http://maven.internal.website/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</mirror>

<mirror>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <mirrorOf>*,!snapshots,!releases</mirrorOf>
    <name>Nexus Public Mirror</name>
    <url>http://maven.internal.website/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</mirror>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMMEDIATELY after posting my question I realized I hadn't tried one pattern... and it seems to work just fine:

```
<mirror>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <mirrorOf>!snapshots,!releases</mirrorOf>
    <name>Nexus Public Mirror</name>
    <url>http://maven.internal.website/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</mirror>
```